# JS Error: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, node.js, datagram

I'm trying to make an App in HbbTV to search for Hue-lamps, for this I need a upnp search. But my Chrome is just showing an error that shouldn't be there, in my opinion.

```js
    const dgram = require('dgram');
    const search = new Buffer([
    'M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1',
    'HOST: 239.255.255.250:1900',
    'MAN: "ssdp:discover"',
    'MX: 3',
    'ST: upnp:rootdevice'
    ].join('\r\n'));

    const socket = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

    socket.on('listening', () => {
    socket.addMembership('239.255.255.250');
    socket.send(search, 0, search.length, 1900, 239.255.255.250); 
    });

    socket.on('message', (message) => {
    console.log(message.toString());
    });
    socket.bind(1900);
```

It shows me an error in line 14:

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Am I overseeing anything, or is something else wrong?

Best regards

Comment: is `socket.send` line 14?  I'm guessing your IP address should be in a string

Comment: The IP address should be a string.

Comment: Make sure you are using correct version of Node JS. Since you are using ECMA 6

Comment: @GauravSharma I downloaded and installed the newest Node.js 8.4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've missed `''` for `239.255.255.250` in next line:

```
socket.send(search, 0, search.length, 1900, 239.255.255.250);
```